# Subir multiples imagenes al servidor con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un fragmento de código que realiza la subida de archivos, en este caso imagenes al servidor y luego guarda el registro en la base de datos [MySQL], la operación funciona pero a veces me resulta lento al intentar subir 2 o 3 imagenes, lo cual me parece extraño ese resultado, comparto el codigo que tengo para ver si me pueden dar alguna sugerencia, Gracias anticipadas.

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
            #Numero de archivos a cargar
                $num_files = count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++)
                {
                    #Ver si hay archivos para subir
                    if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]))
                    {
                        echo "No se encontraron archivos";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        #Copiar imagenes a la carpeta correspondiente de acuerdo a la marca
                        if(@copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i],"$archivo".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i])){
                            $path = "".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
                            $query3= $con->query("INSERT INTO archivoticket(FK_idTicket, archivoTicket) VALUES('$idTick', '$path')");                       
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "No se pudo subir el archivo";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

La velocidad de subida depende de la red y tamaño de los archivos. sin embargo en tu código puedes evitar realizar una conexión a la base por cada archivo. si formas el sql y lo ejecutas al final:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
#Numero de archivos a cargar
    $num_files = count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO archivoticket(FK_idTicket, archivoTicket)";
    $values = '';
    for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++)
    {
        #Ver si hay archivos para subir
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]))
        {
            echo "No se encontraron archivos";
        }
        else
        {
            #Copiar imagenes a la carpeta correspondiente de acuerdo a la marca
            if(@copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i],"$archivo".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i])){
                $path = "".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
                $values .= "('$idTick', '$path'),"; // guardamos los datos para luego ejecutar en una sola instruccion             
            }
            else
            {
                echo "No se pudo subir el archivo";
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($values)) {

      $query = $query . ' VALUES ' . substr($values, 0, -1); //Concatenamos y quitamos la ultima coma de los values
      $query3= $con->query($query);  //ejecutamos el query

   }
}
```

Si la instrucción sql falla ningún archivo se guardara en la base de datos y deberás borrarlos físicamente para no tener basura en el server. pero actualmente tienes el mismo problema.

Te recomiendo lo valides.